boxplot two rasters and one shapefile
The code works with one raster and one shapefile. I tried to expand the code to use stack() for the two rasterfiles (present and future climate, paired boxplots), because extract(r,v) is available for one raster and one shapefile. Do you know of any other possibilities? Isuppose it has to be within library(terra)
# load libraries
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)

# Load shp and raster from example files of terra
(v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")))

(r1 <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")))

(r2 <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")))



r1r2<-stack(r1,r2)
Error in .local(x, ...) : 
 unused argument (new("SpatRaster", ptr = new("Rcpp_SpatRaster", .xData = <environment>)))



# extract, include names from vector attributes
e <- extract(r,v)
e$NAME_2 <- v$NAME_2[e$ID]
str(e)

# plot
ggplot(e, aes(x = NAME_2, y = elevation)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))


Your question really seems to be "how do I combine two SpatRasters into a single object. In your context, the answer is use c
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r1 <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")) 
r2 <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")) * 2

x <- c(r1, r2)
names(x) <- c("A", "B")

#and extract values
e <- extract(x, v)
e$name <- v$NAME_2[e$ID]

To make a boxplot for each polygon and layer, see ?boxplot (or use another plotting approach such as ggplot). For example
f <- reshape(e, varying = names(x), v.names="value", times=names(x), direction="long")
par(mar=c(3,6,1,1), cex.axis=.5)
boxplot(value ~ time:name, data = f, horizontal=TRUE, cex=.25,
        boxwex = 0.5, col = c("orange", "yellow"), las=1,
        sep = ":", lex.order = F, yaxs = "i", ylab="")


Thanks for the valuable answer. This extract just produces two boxplots for r1 and r2. Therefore I added v and ID to > e <- extract(x,v) > e$NAME_2 <- v$NAME_2[e$ID] > str(e)
'data.frame': 4606 obs. of  4 variables:
$ ID    : num  1 1 1
$ A     : int  547 485 497 515 515
$ B     : int  109
$ NAME_2: chr  "Clervaux" "Clervaux" "Clervaux" "Clervaux" ...
Probably boxplot() is not the right function to have NAME_2 on the x-axis and for each class of NAME_2 a boxplot from r1 and a paired boxplot from r2. Whould I us 2 times geom_boxplot() from ggplot()?
